# vb.net example to get google contacts using dotnetopenauth?

Tags: vb.net, oauth, dotnetopenauth

I've read some posts here and found some c# examples but I'm unable to transfer them to vb.net :-( When I translate OAuthConsumer example from dotnetopenauth I always get the following error message:

`'DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock.InMemoryTokenManager' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'.`

in this line:

`Private ReadOnly Property TokenManager() As InMemoryTokenManager`

Is there anywhere a working example for vb.net? I've managed to use OpenID from `dotnetopenauth` to authenticate with Google but now I'm stuck with reading the contacts...
Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: That error message is not related to incurrent conversion between C# and VB.NET, but looks like a change in the DotNetOpenAuth API. When a class is "Friend", they really don't want you to access it. So the sample you found is properly out of date...

Comment: The sample is included in latest dotnetopenauth 3.4.7 supplied on http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/ . There in OAuthConsumer.GoogleAddressbook.aspx.cs the line is _private InMemoryTokenManager TokenManager {_ which is translated as above.

Comment: Alright. If you own the InMemoryTokenManager (if it is in your code files), just make it to public instead of Friend. I though it was a type they supplied in their DLL :)

Comment: @Jesper: Yes, i was not aware that the ApplicationBlock included in the dotnetopenauth could / should be modified but I've made the changes now as proposed also by Andrew below, and now it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ApplicationBlock is a source distribution in the .zip file so that you can copy and paste the bits of it you like directly into your own project, in which case a `Friend` class should work for you just fine.

Comment: Great, that works, thanks! One further question: How could I now avoid that the user has to click 'Grant access' every time?

Comment: @K232: Should ask a new question for this.

Comment: @Valamas: Ok, I will do so. I think I have to save the AccessToken but i noticed that it's a different one for each request even for the same user. But maybe that's caused by pressing 'Grant Access' again and again, probably Google therefore creates a new token everytime. I'll now try to save the token and see whether it's working, otherwise I'll post a new question. Thanks!

Comment: That's somewhat related to this question -- it's because (you may have noticed the comment in the InMemoryTokenManager) the InMemoryTokenManager is *not* for production use.  You must store both the access token and the token secret, which is what the token manager is all about, but you have to write your own `ITokenManager` implementation to do this.

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks for clarification, I will try that, and maybe raise a new question in case of problems ;-)